# How to find an email in Gmail that was snoozed in Google Inbox?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

### UPDATE: Changes to Gmail have made this question less relevant; there is now a Snoozed folder allowing snoozed messages to be easily viewed.

I recently started trying out the new Inbox app from Google. While it generally works side by side with Gmail, there is one thing I can't find a parallel for in Gmail.

When a mail (or reminder) is snoozed in Inbox, it is removed from the inbox but can be found in Inbox by opening the Snoozed label, thus listing the snoozed items. However, looking at Gmail the snoozed items seem only visible in the All Mail view, where they are mixed in with other mail that's archived or still in the inbox but there doesn't seem to be a Snoozed label that would let me view only the snoozed items.

Is this simply a missing feature still to come, or is there some way I've missed that would let me view just the snoozed items within traditional Gmail?

Comment: 1. Tags should not be added to titles. Ref https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging

Comment: 2. I think that the question is still valid and instead of adding note saying that the question is outdated, an answer briefly describing the relevant new features should be posted. Bear in mind that as the OP you could change the accepted answer at anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [the answer from @psacc](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/69913/22178) was previously the one I was looking for, recent changes to Gmail have added full support for snoozing. This includes a **Snoozed** "folder" that can be used to view snoozed messages.

[image]

Comment: I'm finding that this shows me only recently snoozed messages/threads, not all snoozed since the beginning of the feature. Not sure if I should consider this a separate question rather than looking for the solution on this one, but in any case, the above isn't proving a very satisfactory fix (albeit better than not having any Snoozed folder, as long as I know it's incomplete).

Answer (score 33):

Searching for "[label:snoozed](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#label/snoozed)" lists Inbox snoozed emails in Gmail. But snoozed does not seem to behave like any normal label in gmail as you can not apply it other emails.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Exactly what I wanted. So the snoozed label exists but is treated a little differently in not appearing in the list of labels; you need to search for it.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how the snooze-until time is represented? Is it represented by something that Gmail or other mail readers can access?  Is it a property visible in IMAP?

Comment: Thanks! Note you can also "create" the "snoozed" label in gmail, and it will then show up in the labels list. Clicking on the "snoozed" label essentially just searches for `label:snoozed` so this works just fine! Some caveats: you cannot "snooze" in gmail by adding this label, and you cannot see "Someday" snoozes.

Answer (score 13):

If the email already returned to the inbox (after snoozing), I discovered I can search using `is:pinned` because the email will be pinned.

Comment: is:pinned not working anymore. Do you know any other method?

Comment: It works. I just tried `in:pinned`, and although Gmail autocorrected it to `label:pinned`, the search worked. You will see a lot of seemingly non-snoozed emails too, but they were snoozed at some point in their lifespan. I couldn't however, seem to combine `label:pinned AND in:snoozed` both of which work individually.

Answer (score 0):

`in:snoozed` in the Gmail search bar now works.

Answer (score -3):

You can click the "All Mail" button (below "Drafts", in the left panel of Gmail).  The snoozed email should be in that "All Mail" inbox. Hope this helps.

Edit: Also, while you are viewing that email, you can click the "Move to Inbox" button to move it back to your Gmail inbox.  But this also means your email will no longer be snoozed in "Inbox" app.

Comment: Yes, I know how to use Gmail. I currently have 26,793 messages in All Mail; how would you suggest I find the ones amongst those that have been snoozed? That is the information I was actually looking for.

Answer (score -5):

just create a new label into Gmail with the name "snoozed",  then all the snoozed emails in Google Inbox will be available into Gmail.

Comment: After trying this and seeing that it doesn't work I found a snoozed message in Gmail by searching for its subject. I saw that it didn't have any visible labels that could be used for something like this.