# How to access "Snoozed" messages via IMAP in Gmail

Tags: inbox-by-gmail, imap, gmail-imap

NOTE: This question was originally asked about "Inbox by Gmail", when it existed, but Inbox has been retired and its Snooze feature rolled into Gmail. This question now applies to the Snoozed messages in Gmail.

---

Pending the shutdown of Mailbox from Dropbox, I'm exploring other apps that can offer the same kind of message postpone features. Gmail <s>Inbox</s> with Snooze is pretty close, except I also would like to access the "snoozed" emails via IMAP. (I'm writing the code, so it could be either IMAP or Gmail API.)

Is there a way to get the list of "snoozed" messages for Gmail <s>Inbox</s> programmatically?

Note that I'm not optimistic at this point, because [this recent feature request for an email client](https://github.com/nylas/N1/issues/312) requests the same thing, and the author (who probably knows more about the Gmail API than I do) says it's not possible:

> Unfortunately, we can't support the categories in Google Inbox because they aren't exposed via the Gmail API or the Gmail IMAP interface. They're only available from Google Inbox itself.

I am also aware of [How to find an email in Gmail that was snoozed in Google Inbox?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69906/how-to-find-an-email-in-gmail-that-was-snoozed-in-google-inbox) which shows how to view snoozed emails from the traditional Gmail interface, but I can't seem to apply the same approach to IMAP.

Comment: Interesting. I don't even see such a feature in my Gmail, so can't test it but if, as you have already pointed out that "Snoozed" is a label then can't see why wouldn't it be possible to fetch by "snoozed" label.

Comment: @matcheek: The feature I'm referring to is available at https://inbox.google.com, not the older https://mail.google.com interface. If you can find a way to fetch the "snoozed" label via IMAP, the details of how to do that would be an excellent answer to this question.

Comment: I haven't found an answer to *this* question, but I've found a solution to the real problem I was trying to solve. [Spark by Readdle](https://readdle.com/products/spark) provides all the features I liked from Mailbox, and it's better.

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

In your IMAP client try using search to find unread messages as "snooze" is not the same as any other Gmail feature.

## Explanation

From [How Inbox works with Gmail - Inbox by Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6098273?hl=en)

> Gmail and Inbox have many of the same features, but there are
> differences.

Gmail's read later (mark as unread) is similar to [Snooze](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067583?hl=en) but no the same. One of the main differences it that Snooze isn't implemented as a direct equivalent of an IMAP supported feature.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I am looking for a way to access Inbox "Snoozed" messages via IMAP or Gmail API. Saying "Snooze isn't implemented as a direct equivalent of an IMAP supported feature" is not helpful.

Comment: I disagree with you. My post answers the question, but unfortunately it not say what you want and it not say what you want because, AFAIK, what you want it's not possible.

Comment: @GregHewgill he means you simply can't. I just tested it myself too, Snooze and Done move messages to somewhere out of reach of IMAP clients