# How can I use Google Inbox's "snooze" in regular Gmail?

Tags: gmail, inbox-by-gmail

Is there a way to "snooze" an email within Gmail without going to Google Inbox? Do some apps support it but not others? I'm interested in the Gmail web app, in particular (mail.google.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without using a third-party app, or using something like a label with a date. You'd still need to manually move the messages back to your inbox.

See also: [How to find an email in Gmail that was snoozed in Google Inbox?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69906/354)